# Is it possible to style the footers differently without adding divs or something else?

Tags: html, css

[image: HTML CODE]

Hi! I have gotten a CSS styling lesson in my webdevelopment class. They told me to not touch ANYTHING in the HTML code (See picture).
The first 2 footers should be styled as "Written by ..." under an article. And the last footer should be styled as a real footer at the bottom of the page. Can I style these differently with CSS without changing anything in the HTML code? Im not allowed to add divs or anything.

My web development class is really outdated...

Comment: `#wrapper > footer { ... }` for the last one `section footer { ... }` for the other two

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], where it says, "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) That is actually a good thing to know. Since there can be cases where you cannot change source code, only CSS. And it can happen more than you can think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to look at here is how can your CSS selector differ from one element to the other.

Since you cannot touch the HTML to add a class to the article footers or an ID to the site footer, you need to look at what contains them. This is where the answer commented comes in.

The site's footer is a direct descendant of the `#wrapper` div while the article footers are nested in the `section`.

It's important that without a class or ID, you need to specify the site footer as a direct descendant using what is called the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>` in your CSS, and that the article footers are selected based on their parent being a section.

```
#wrapper > footer { ... }
section footer { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didnt know this combinator existed, I am very new to this. Have good day!